# DES encrypt file less than 64 bytes

Tags: encryption, cryptography, des

I want to create an encryption program for studies using the DES algorithm. If my data is more than 64 bytes I can use CBC or EBC mode to encrypt it. But what if my data file is less than 64 bytes? Should I add white spaces at the end of the file to fill it and get 64 bytes? What is a good approach?

Comment: You mean more than 64-bit. DES [insecure](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/62771/is-des-secure-under-cbc/62772#62772), ECB also insecure. Use AES and preferably AES-GCM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DES block size is 64 *bits,* or 8 bytes. If your message is less than 8 bytes, you need to pad it. A [common scheme](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2898#section-6.1.1) is to fill out the block by repeatedly appending the length of the padding. For example, if your message is 3 bytes, and you need to fill an 8-byte block, you need 5 bytes of padding. Append the value 5, 5 times, to the message:

```
// Message ABC + 5 bytes of padding
0x41 0x42 0x43 + 0x05 0x05 0x05 0x05 0x05
```

This implies you need at least one byte of padding, so if your message is a complete block, you need to add a whole extra block just for padding. To remove the padding, look at the value of the last byte, *N*, and verify that the last *N* bytes of the plain text have that same value.

Comment: This is known as [PKCS5 or PKCS7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS#5_and_PKCS#7) padding.